# Mysql table repair failed: "Can't create new tempfile"

Tags: mysql

I run a WordPress website. Today I found that wp_posts table is crashed. When I tried to repair the table, I got the following error:

```
REPAIR TABLE wp_posts;

error Can't create new tempfile: './[databasename]/wp_posts.TMD' 

repair  status    Operation failed
```

I tried to run the following command in shell:

```
myisamchk -r -f wp_posts.MYI

error: File 'wp_posts.MYI' doesn't exist
```

Can you please tell me what else I can try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Turned out that "`myisamchk -r -f wp_posts.MYI`" was the correct solution. I just had to go to the data folder.

In my CentOS system, I changed directory to `/var/lib/mysql/[database]/`and found `wp_posts.MYI`

After removing this file, repair was successful.

Comment: worked for me too! But, someone knows why this happens?  I dont wanna do this again hahahah

Answer (score 23):

Try stopping your service using the following command `sudo service mysql stop`

Now do the repair check `myisamchk -r -f -o /var/lib/mysql/DatabaseName/wp_posts`

Start your service and enjoy it!

It works for me

Comment: This is magic. Thank you s much! You saved me. 

I tried. 

`sudo myisamchk -r -f -o /var/lib/mysql/[dbname]/wp_options`

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same trouble.  The problem was the .TMD file already existed and mysqlrepair refused to overwrite it.  I removed the .TMD file and the mysqlrepair worked famously.  I had to stop the process attempting to use the crashed table, then run the repair.

Comment: I did the same and it fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
```

Then go to:
/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

That should take effect and automatically repair your crashed table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Once you've done the repair, do not forget to remove this line from your wp-config.php file. The URL /wp-admin/maint/repair.php is accessible by non authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

For mariaDB and some other combination of OS and DB version, the file may also be located under `/config/databases/[DATABASE]`.
Try to run **as root** (`sudo su`):

```
service mysql stop
myisamchk -rf /config/databases/[databasename]/wp_posts.MYI
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this error in phpMyadmin, I got around it by navigating to /var/lib/mysql/[database]/ and deleting the TMD file for the table I was trying to repair (not the MYI file as stated in the explanation above).

When I tried getting rid of the MYI file, the repair operation didn't work.