# Mysql table repair failed: “Can't create new tempfile”

Tags: mysql, vps

I'm facing the same problem shown in this thread: [Mysql table repair failed: "Can't create new tempfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684585/mysql-table-repair-failed-cant-create-new-tempfile)

I'm a newbie here. So please consider this while reading the question. In the above thread, this was the solution:

```
service mysql stop
myisamchk -rf /config/databases/[databasename]/wp_posts.MYI
service mysql start
```

What if I have a different database name?

For example, if I'm seeing the error:

> Can't create new tempfile: './waputepr_wp167/wpdm_redirection_404`

then this should be the correct line, right?

```
service mysql stop
myisamchk -rf /config/databases/waputepr_wp167/wp_posts.MYI
service mysql start
```

Is this approach correct?

Comment: If `/config/databases/` is the path to your databases, then yes. You would need to extrapolate the values from the answer to match your environment. Since this is essentially a question regarding usage of already provided answers, I am going to flag this question as duplicate.

Comment: @Will B, thank you for your reply, but how can i find the path to my database?

Comment: See: [How to find the mysql data directory from command line in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17968287/1144627) the answers given apply to all platforms.

Comment: @Will B, in the above i think i made mistake? this should be line right?  /var/lib/mysql/waputepr_wp167/wpdm_redirection_404.MYI

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out to solve the problem. Below are the steps.

Comment: service mysqld start, myisamchk -r -f -o /var/lib/mysql/Databasename/wpdm_redirection_404, service mysqld stop.